# How does the plotting function of pandas and matplotlib sync?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I'm new. Look at the snippet of the code that results in a graph.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data/GOOG.csv")
    df['High'].plot()
    plt.show()
```

My question is - *how plt.show() (matplotlib.pyplot) is getting the values of x and y when plt is **not** being called with any parameters*? The plot function is of the dataframe object. Does it store the value somewhere default from which plt can get the values?

Comment: `plt.show()` does not 'plot' the values, it will show the current already creaetd figure(s). And it is `df['High'].plot()` which creates this figure under the hood.

Comment: Could you post it as answer so that I could accept?

Comment: All of the pandas plotting functions are implemented by calling out to mpl.

Answer (score 1):

`plt.show()` does not 'plot' the values, it will show the current already created figure(s).
It is `df['High'].plot()` which creates this figure under the hood. The pandas plotting functions are implemented by calling out to matplotlib. By default, it will create a new figure, unless the specify with the `ax` keyword argument a subplot on which to add the plot.